# error in implementation of random forest in mice r package

Tags: r, random-forest, r-mice

Here is just example data:

```
# generation of correlated data   
matrixCR <- matrix(NA, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
diag(matrixCR) <- 1
matrixCR[upper.tri (matrixCR, diag = FALSE)] <- 0.5
matrixCR[lower.tri (matrixCR, diag = FALSE)] <- 0.5
matrixCR[1:10,1:10]
L = chol(matrixCR)# Cholesky decomposition
nvars = dim(L)[1]
nobs = 200
set.seed(123)
rM = t(L) %*% matrix(rnorm(nvars*nobs), nrow=nvars, ncol=nobs)
rM1 <- t(rM)
rownames(rM1) <- paste("S", 1:200, sep = "") 
colnames(rM1) <- paste("M", 1:100, sep = "")
# introducing missing value to the dataset 
N <- 2000*0.05 # 5% random missing values 
inds <- round ( runif(N, 1, length(rM1)) )
rM1[inds] <- NA


# using random forest implemented in mice package 
require(mice)
out.imp <- mice(rM1, m = 5, method ="rf")
imp.data <- complete(out.imp)
```

I am getting following error:

```
 iter imp variable
  1   1  M1  M2Error in apply(forest, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(s) sample(unlist(s),  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I am not sure what is causing this problem ?

Comment: The `mice` function seems to be throwing an error whenever it gets to a column with only a single missing value. I figured this out by running your code and successively excluding the columns where it failed. Then I compared the failing and succeeding columns and the only difference was that the failing columns had only one `NA` value.  When I recreated your matrix, but with a 50% chance of a missing value (so no column would have only one `NA`) the code ran fine. I don't know if this is a bug or if there's some reason why having only one `NA` in a column should cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, when the `method` is set to randomforest (`rf`), the `mice` function is throwing an error whenever it gets to a column with only a single `NA`value, but runs fine with any other number of `NA` values.

I checked with the package author and this appears to be a bug. Until it's fixed, you can choose a different imputation method for those columns with a single `NA` value. For example:

```
# Count number of NA in each column
NAcount = apply(rM1, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

# Create a vector giving the imputation method to use for each column. 
# Set it to "rf" unless that column has exactly one NA value.
method = rep("rf", ncol(rM1))
method[which(NAcount==1)] = "norm"

# Run the imputation with the new "method" selections
out.imp <- mice(rM1, m = 5, method = method)
```

I realize that for consistency you may want to use the same imputation method for all the columns, but the above gives you an option if you're set on using the randomforest method.